# Content Security Policy with Ruby on Rails running on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I'm wondering how I can set CSP on a Ruby on Rails app that is deployed using Heroku?

I added the following to `config/initializers/content_security_policy.rb` [as described in the official docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#content-security-policy-header):

```
Rails.application.config.content_security_policy do |policy|
  policy.default_src :self, :https
  policy.font_src :self, :https, :data
  policy.img_src :self, :https, :data
  policy.object_src :none
  policy.script_src :self, :https
  policy.style_src :self, :https
  # Specify URI for violation reports
  # policy.report_uri '/csp-violation-report-endpoint'
end

Rails.application.config.content_security_policy_nonce_generator = ->(_request) { SecureRandom.base64(16) }
```

Unfortunately the header is not being set on the app once deployed.

I'm using the Ruby on Rails server to serve both the backend API as well as the frontend (a single page application using Vue.js).

I'm wondering if it's even possible to set CSP in this setup?